# Is there a way to CAST multiple bit columns into int instead of rewriting CAST for each column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, int, bit

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and trying to pull a query to include all the bit columns which are in nature binary (either 0 or 1) and add a column to indicate whether the sum of these columns is greater than 1.
The issue is that all the column are bit datatypes and I need to cast them to int in order to do any addition. I want to know if there was a easier way to CAST multiple columns instead of rewriting the CAST function for each column.

For example, if these columns are all in bit:

```
student, graduated, incomplete


SELECT CASE 
 WHEN CAST(student AS INT) + CAST(graduated AS INT) + CAST(incomplete AS INT) > 0 
    THEN 'complete' END AS status_shown
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cast at all:

```
select (case when student = 1 or graduated = 1 or incomplete = 1
             then 'complete'
        end) as status_shown
from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If columns are BITs - this can help:

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN t.student|t.graduated|t.incomplete THEN 'complete' END AS [status_shown] 
FROM table1 t;
```